# Compute $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$ without using L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Purely out of curiosity, is it possible to compute the following limit without using L'Hopital?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$$

Using L'Hopital and realizing that we cannot get what we want if we simply take derivatives of $e^{-1/x^2}$ and $x$ directly, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1/x}{e^{1/x^2}}=0$$

I am curious about whether there is a different way of computing this.

Comment: Since $e^{-1/x^2}$ is not analytic near $0$, the standard approach of power series won't work here.  You could try the change of variables $\frac{1}{x}=y$ and take the limit of $\frac{y}{e^{y^2}}$ as $y$ goes to infinity and estimate the size of the denominator.

Comment: It's l'Hopital - there is no s in there. (Or if you want to be fully correct, it's l'Hôpital, but I'd be fine with leaving out accents for convenience.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution of limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337367/solution-of-limit-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-e-1-x2x)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350418/evaluating-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frace-1-x2x)

Comment: It doesn't since the answers there used L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the change of variables: $t=\frac{1}{x}$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t^2}}$$
now observe that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{t^2}}{t}=+\infty$$
since $e^{t^2}\ge 1+t^2$ ($e^x\ge 1+x$ for all $x$ is a well known thing)

Hence $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t^2}}=0$$

Comment: I was just writing this.  :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different method:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{e^{\ln(x)}}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-(\frac{1}{x^2}+\ln(x))}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{x}+x\ln(x))}=0$$