# How to calculate $\exp(-\frac{1}{x^4})/x$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to calculate this limit? I read that it is zero, but how to show it?

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{x}$$

I tried l‘Hôpital and series expension of exp, however I can not get any results.

l‘Hôpital:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{4 x^5} $$

Series:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-1/x^4+1/(2x^8)…}{x} $$

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: edited

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350418/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168549/42969

Comment: This answers your question [Compute $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$ without using L'Hopital?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168549/compute-lim-x-to-0-frace-1-x2x-without-using-lhopital) (+$y=x^2$ and $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^4}}}x=x\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{y^2}}}y$).